# Maximum update depth exceeded while trying to liftup function to child via props

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm holding an array of json inside my main component, and I've created an "FormComponent" which hold the the inputs.

I've created an 'add' function inside the parent component and I'm trying to send it to child via prop under the name `createTODOhander` as you can see here:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Task from "./Task";
import FormComponent from "./FormComponent";


class TodoList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        MAXIMUMJOBS: 5,
        TodoList: [],
    }
    createTODO = (Todoname) => {
        this.setState({
            TodoList: this.state.TodoList.concat({Todoname: Todoname})
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginLeft: '10px'}}>
                <h3>You can enter {this.state.MAXIMUMJOBS - this.state.TodoList.length} TODO list jobs.</h3>
                <FormComponent createTODOhandler={this.createTODO()} />
            )
    }
}
```

On the `FormComponent` I'm trying to use it this way:

```
import * as React from "react";


class FormComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        inputValue: ''
    }
    inputChanged = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            inputValue: e.target.value
        })
    };
    createTODO = () => {
        if (this.state.inputValue === '') {}//do nothing, not gonna happen because the button is disabled.
        else{
            this.props.createTODOhandler(this.state.inputValue);
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.inputChanged} value={this.state.inputValue}
                       placeholder={"Enter your job here."}/>
                &nbsp;
                <button onClick={this.createTODO}>Add!</button>
                &nbsp;
                <button>Clear list</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FormComponent;
```

But I get an `Maximum update depth exceeded.` Error,

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have remove `()` from the props.

This `<FormComponent createTODOhandler={this.createTODO()} />`

Changed to: `<FormComponent createTODOhandler={this.createTODO} />`

Answer (score 2):

This is your bug:

```
<FormComponent createTODOhandler={this.createTODO()} />
```

You are executing the function each time you render the component. You need to only have reference to the function instead:

```
<FormComponent createTODOhandler={this.createTODO} />
```